# Just trying to make a simple calculator, but it keeps saying "Invalid Syntax: Perhaps you forgot a comma"

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
operation = str(input("Operation (type which operation you would like): "))
if operation == "division":
    number1 = float(input("1st Number? "))
    number2 = float(input("2nd Number? "))
    quotient = number1 / number2
    print(str(number1) + " / " + str(number2) " = " + str(division))
elif operation == "multiplication":
    number1 = float(input("1st Number? "))
    number2 = float(input("2nd Number? "))
    product = number1 * number2
    print(str(number1) + " * " + str(number2) + " = " + str(product))
elif operation == "addition":
    number1 = float(input("1st Number? "))
    number2 = float(input("2nd Number? "))
    summary = number1 + number2
    print(str(number1) + " * " + str(number2) + " = " + str(summary))
elif operation == "exponent":
    number1 = float(input("Number? "))
    exponent = float(input("Exponent? "))
    product2 = number1 ** exponent
    print(str(number1) + "^" + str(exponent) + " = " + str(product2))
```

The 'S' in 'str' was highlighted
I realized I didn't put "elif", so I tried that, still didn't work.
Don't know what's going wrong, perhaps some of you can answer

Comment: I believe you are missing a `+` in your first `print` statement

Comment: `str(number2) " = "` You missed `+` between `) ` and `"`.

Comment: Posting the full traceback should be mandatory on questions like this. It's a lot easier for us to help you if you include the entire error message.

Comment: You've left a `*` in line 16 where it should be a `+`
Not a bug, just a typo. The bug is already mentioned above.

Comment: Bros thanks soo much, i don't know how i missed that... and the "*"

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you're missing a `+` sign in your `if` block. I'm putting the fix here for readability

```
if operation == "division":
    number1 = float(input("1st Number? "))
    number2 = float(input("2nd Number? "))
    quotient = number1 / number2
    # the issue is here ----------------------v
    print(str(number1) + " / " + str(number2) + " = " + str(division))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a 2nd error in your first print: you put `str(division)` instead of `str(quotient)` (division is not defined)